Unable to run Angular application using npm run local
I am working on hybrid angular application using angular 8 and angular 1. Earlier I used to run application on my Ubuntu system using commnad npm run local and app used to work fine locally, but for some reason i changed my laptop to windows OS and now when i am trying to run the same application using command npm run local. It is giving me following error
<--- Last few GCs --->

[19920:0000021BF1602F90]   187373 ms: Scavenge 1363.8 (1424.5) -> 1363.2 (1425.0) MB, 4.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.228, current mu = 0.191) allocation failure
[19920:0000021BF1602F90]   187379 ms: Scavenge 1363.8 (1425.0) -> 1363.4 (1425.5) MB, 4.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.228, current mu = 0.191) allocation failure
[19920:0000021BF1602F90]   187387 ms: Scavenge 1364.2 (1425.5) -> 1363.6 (1426.0) MB, 3.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.228, current mu = 0.191) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 000001D3AA25C5C1]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 000001D3AA253038]
Security context: 0x027c9569e6e9 <JSObject>
    2: split [0000027C956906C9](this=0x009ac22eeff9 <String[77]: C:/Project/web-frontend/node_modules/create-ecdh/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js>,0x01e9cac31611 <JSRegExp <String[3]: \/+>>)
    3: computeSourceURL [000003FA8A752069] [C:\Project\web-frontend\node_modules\source-map\lib\util.js:~441] [pc=000001D3AC1BBCFF...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7E6D9832A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF7E6D72DB6 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF7E6D73730 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF7E708C14E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF7E708C07F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF7E7272874 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 00007FF7E7269856 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
 8: 00007FF7E7267EAC v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
 9: 00007FF7E7270BF7 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
10: 00007FF7E7270C76 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
11: 00007FF7E739AF17 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
12: 00007FF7E7418106 v8::internal::operator<<+73494
13: 000001D3AA25C5C1
Note: This command was run via npm module 'win-node-env'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! portal.abced.com@1.0.1 local: `NODE_ENV=local webpack-dev-server --mode development --progress --watch --colors true --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portal.abced.com@1.0.1 local script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mohit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-20T11_27_07_432Z-debug.log


i even set the heap memory allocation using the commnand set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" but still it is not working
Below is the script content of the file:
  "scripts": {
    "local": "NODE_ENV=local webpack-dev-server --mode development --progress --watch --colors true --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080",
    "dev": " NODE_ENV=dev webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "stage": "NODE_ENV=stage webpack --config webpack.production.config.js",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=prod webpack --config webpack.production.config.js",
    "beta": "NODE_ENV=beta webpack --config webpack.production.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev&&webpack-dev-server --progress --colors true --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080"
  }


try to increase --max-old-space-size upto 9000
